# None memory location

Tags: python, memory, nonetype

When I type `id(None)` into a Python interpreter, I get `9545840`.  I can open another terminal and do the same thing, and I get the same result even if the first terminal has been closed, so apparently `None` has been assigned a place in memory that has been reserved.  When is that memory location decided on?  Is it something that changes on every reboot, or is it decided when Python is installed?  Is it different on different computers?

Comment: `>>> id(None)
9545840` I got the same value on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I get different values when opening 1) ipython and 2) jupyter qtconsole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CPython implementation None is declared as static global object:

```
PyAPI_DATA(PyObject) _Py_NoneStruct; /* Don't use this directly */
#define Py_None (&_Py_NoneStruct)
```

This means that you will likely get the same result, as long as you use the same version of interpreter, built for the same environment with the same compilation options.

This is not specified in Python's documentation however, so other Python implementations might behave differently. The only guarantee is that it will be constant within lifetime of `None` object, that is, single execution of interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The memory location of `None` is statically allocated. It is set, when python is compiled. So different versions of CPython has different ids.